# Change the shortcut to move windows from Alt to Super/Meta in Unity-2D

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I change the window movement key when using Unity 2D?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77438/how-can-i-change-the-window-movement-key-when-using-unity-2d)

There is already [an answered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66125/how-to-change-the-shortcut-to-move-windows-from-alt-to-super-meta) about this but it's only for regular Unity. I've looked through several entries in dconf-editor and can't find anything that could be related.

Also installed the Unity-2D configuration tool from Mariano Chavero but it doesn't have that option. Gnome Tweak Tool also doesn't have that option.

How can I accomplish the same thing in Unity-2D?